# Prove chain-completeness of a poset

Tags: order-theory

How can I prove chain-completeness of a poset?
In particular this is the problem:

$\langle D, \leq \rangle$ is a chain-complete poset (every chain has a least upper bound). Prove or disprove $\langle convex(D),\subseteq \rangle$ is a chain-complete poset.

Where $convex(D)=\{S \subseteq D |\forall x,y\in S, z\in D. (x\leq z \leq y \Rightarrow z\in S\}$

My naive opinion, probably wrong:

I think, it's quite obvious that is true, and given a chain $c_1,c_2,...,c_n \in convex(D)$, $c_1\subseteq c_2...\subseteq c_n$ we just take $c_n$ as LUB.

Comment: Where it says $S\subseteq$, do you mean $S\subseteq D$?

Comment: In your last paragraph, you seem to be assuming that $D$ or at least $\operatorname{convex}(D)$ is finite. Is this a premise that you forgot to state?

Comment: No, finiteness is not a premise. Honestly I don't have any ideas in how to approach this, and probably my last paragraph is completely wrong

Comment: Since $\mathrm{convex}(D)$ is ordered by inclusion an obvious candidate for the least upper bound of a chain $\{c_i\mid i\in I\}$ is $\bigcup_{i\in I} c_i$. Can you see why this does (or doesn't) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $\langle \operatorname{convex}(D),\subseteq\rangle$ is chain-complete, it suffices to show that for any chain $C_i$ in $\operatorname{convex}(D)$ with $C_i\subseteq C_{i+1}$ the union $C=\bigcup_iC_i$ is also in $\operatorname{convex}(D)$, since this can then serve as the least upper bound. This is trivial if the chain is finite, since in that case $C$ is its last element.

To prove that $C\in\operatorname{convex}(D)$ also for infinite chains, let $x,y\in C$ be given. Then $x\in C_i$ and $y\in C_j$; without loss of generality assume $i\le j$. Then also $x\in C_j$, so $x,y\in C_j$ and thus for all $z\in D$ we have $x\le z\le y\Rightarrow z\in C_j$ and thus also $x\le z\le y\Rightarrow z\in C$. Thus $C\in \operatorname{convex}(D)$.